# how display Advertisements in bottom of the screen in android?

Tags: android

In my application i want to be use advertisements.Let me know which controls are use for displaying the SLIDE OUT AD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mobile advertising framework such as AdMob, http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android

I think you can use GoogleAds on mobile as well (iPhone, not sure about android)

Hope that helps