# How to add advertisment in bottom of android application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how display Advertisements in bottom of the screen in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220326/how-display-advertisements-in-bottom-of-the-screen-in-android)

I want to create the advertisement bottom of the android application. The size of the bottom advertisement place is 20px.  How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to accept answers to some of your previous questions if you want to inspire people to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to join [Google AdSense for Mobile Applications](http://www.google.com/ads/mobileapps/). In the [help pages](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/topic.py?topic=22415) there is a [mention of an AdSense SDK](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=152909) which might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SDK of one of the mobile advertising providers and place their UI component in your Activity layout.

Comment: And if you want to have your own server side, is there any open source php for control panel?